# Some rstudioapi methods seem to be missing

Tags: r, rstudio

Why does this throw Error: Function selectFile not found in RStudio?

```
install.packages("rstudioapi")

library(rstudioapi)

file_name = rstudioapi::selectFile(caption = "Select File", label = "Select", path = NULL,filter = NULL, existing = TRUE)
```

Comment: What version of RStudio are you using? What version of the `rstudioapi` package is installed?

Comment: RStudio: Version 1.0.136; rstudioapi_0.10

Comment: It's this function call that is not working:   callFun("selectFile", caption, label, path)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `?selectFile` page

> The selectFile and selectDirectory functions were added in version 1.1.287 of RStudio.

So if you are using `RStudio: Version 1.0.136`, then those functions will not work. You will need to update RStudio to a newer version.